# How can I use tf.string_split() in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to get the extension of image files to invoke different image decoder, and I found there's a function called tf.string_split in tensorflow r0.11.

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames, shuffle=shuffle)
reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
img_src, img_bytes = reader.read(filename_queue)
split_result = tf.string_split(img_src, '.')
```

But when I run it, I get this error：

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 0 for 'StringSplit' (op: 'StringSplit') with input shapes: [], [].
```

I think it may caused by the shape inference of `img_src`. I try to use `img_src.set_shape([1,])` to fix it, but it seems not work, I get this error:

```
ValueError: Shapes () and (1,) are not compatible
```

Also, I can't get the shape of `img_src` using

```
tf.Print(split_result, [tf.shape(img_src)],'img_src shape=')
```

The result is `img_src shape=[]`. But if I use the following code:

```
tf.Print(split_result, [img_src],'img_src=')
```

The result is `img_src=test_img/test1.png`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try to pack `img_src`. Just try `split_result = tf.string_split([img_src], '.')` and tell me if it works

Comment: It works!!! Thanks so much!!!

Comment: You're welcome. I move the comment into an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just pack `img_src` into a tensor.

```
split_result = tf.string_split([img_src], '.')
```